# Open a href link in the same pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am working on a pop up window which displays the list of store locations. For each location there are links for google maps(maps and directions).

My question is that, when I click on maps and directions link, I would like to open the google map on the same pop up window, it will have a back button at the end which will take me back to the previous window. Right now, every time, I click on maps and directions, it is opening in the browser window.

@charlietfl. Ok. So I have a product page with a link Check Store Availability. When I click on the link, I use jquery dialog to open a new pop up dialog box. This is a jsp page. In this page, I have a Search text where I can search the list of stores by zipcode. On Search, I do an ajax call, to get the list of stores as a json and display them on the jsp. Now for each stores there is a link for maps and directions which will take me to google maps.

For example `<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003" id="mapDirections_0" target="_self">map & directions<a>`. My aim is when the user clicks on this link, the map will be displayed on the same pop up jsp.

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using <a> tag? if so you can use the target attribute as `<a target="_self" href="#">Link</a>`

Comment: define `same popup window`. Without any code shown we don't know what you are currently doing to help change it

Comment: @shrestha_aj..Yes I am using <a> tag. I tried using target="_self" but it didn't work.

Comment: As @charlietfl said without any code not much help can be provided to you.

Comment: @shrestha_aj..I have added some more details regarding the pop up thing. Let me know what exact code you want. I can provide that.

Answer (score 1):

For popup windows, you should probably use the window.open method.
As for your question, all you have to do is specify the second parameter (name) when you do the window.open() call.

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

- EDIT :
  I decided to update the code to also reflect the creation of a reference variable with which you can reference directly a specific opened window.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

I'll attach a bit of code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    var winref;

    function pop1(){
        winref = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','popwin','width=640, height=480');
    }

    function pop2(){
        window.open('http://google.com','popwin','width=640, height=480');

    }

    function navigate(){
        winref.location.href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web";
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="pop1()">Open first</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="pop2()">Open second</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="navigate()">Navigate 1st window</a>
</body>
</html>
```